# I get wrong answers in multiplying word to byte in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm working on an assignment in assembly 8086 and I get wrong answer; can anyone guess what is my problem? I want to multiply a word to byte.... here is my code:

```
STSEG SEGMENT

  DB 64 DUP(?)

STSEG ENDS
;--------

DTSEG SEGMENT

    D1    DW 6454H
    D2    DB 44H
    REPLY DW 2 DUP(?)

DTSEG ENDS
;--------

CDSEG SEGMENT

    MAIN PROC FAR 
        ASSUME DS:DTSEG, SS:STSEG, CS:CDSEG

        MOV AX,DTSEG
        MOV DS,AX
        MOV AX,0

        MOV AL,D2
        MOV BX,D1
        MUL BL
        MOV REPLY,AX
        MOV REPLY+2,DX

    MAIN ENDP 
    CDSEG ENDS
```

Comment: `mul bl` -> result in `ax`. Please [read the instruction reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html).

Comment: Your problem description seems indicative of a problem too.  If you are "multiplying a word to a byte" you will usually need at *least* a word to store the result.  Hence, multiplying by a byte results in a word, multiplying by a word results in a double word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Jose's answer and to show that

- clearing a register is best done using `xor reg, reg`
- you can multiply straight from memory and not need the extra register

this:

```
xor  ax, ax
mov  al, D2
mul  D1            <-- DX:AX = AX * D1
mov  REPLY, ax
mov  REPLY+2, dx
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply by `BX` :

```
    MOV AX,0
    MOV AL,D2
    MOV BX,D1
    MUL BX          ;◄■■ BX*AX = DX:AX.
    MOV REPLY,AX
    MOV REPLY+2,DX
```